# Financial Word Problem Setup.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

> A person spends one-third of his income, saves one-fourth, and pays away $5$ percent on the whole as interest at $7\frac{1}{2}$ percent on debts previously incurred, and then has $110$ pounds remaining: What was the amount of his debts?

I don't quite understand some of the wording in this problem:

1. *...saves one-fourth...*

Saves one-fourth of his whole income or just the $\frac{2}{3}$ he has left?
I'm not quite certain.

2. *..., and pays away 5 percent on the whole as $7\frac{1}{2}$ percent on debts previously incurred, ...*

So he **just** pays $7\frac{1}{2}$ percent on the 5 percent of the whole or he pays $7\frac{1}{2}$ percent on the 5 percent of the whole **plus** everything else that he had payed before that.

I'm not very good at word problems, so bear with me. Ask me any questions regarding my confusion or the problem. As a side note, the answer to this problem is apparently 200 pounds (which I'm still unable to obtain).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the income is $\$x$.

The word ‘on the whole’ indicates that he spent $\frac x3$, $\frac x4$, and $0.05x$.

Let the debt be $\$d$. Then $$0.05x=0.075d$$

He also has $$x=\frac x3 +\frac x4 +0.05x +110$$

The rest should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Let total income be $x$. The person spends $x/3$, saves $x/4$, and payes $0.05x$ in interest, which means he has $x - x/3 - x/4 - 0.05x$ left. You should be able to get to the answer from here.